# Prove that $u(x,y)$ is constant given that $u(x,y)\geq 0$ and harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $u(x,y)$ is a harmonic function with the property that $u(x,y)\geq 0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ where $u$ is the real part of $f(z)$.
Show $u(x,y)$ is constant.

Consider $$\begin{align}g(z) &= e^{-f(z)}\\ |g(z)| &= |e^{-u(x,y)}| \leq 1 \qquad \text{since $u(x,y) \geq 0$.}\end{align}$$
By Louiville's Theorem, $g$ is constant as $e^{-f(z)}$ is entire (???).
That's all that I've gotten up to, I'm not sure what this has to do with $u$ being harmonic. I can think of maybe it implies that $f$ is holomorphic but that's it.

Comment: Using the exponential function is cumbersome because its inverse is not everywhere analytic.  Use $g(z)=1/(1+f(z))$.

Comment: Why do we need to consider the inverse of the exponential here?

Comment: $g(z)=1/2$, let's say.  Is $f(z)$ the real value of $\ln 2$, or that number plus or a multiple of $2\pi i$?  You have to jump through extra hoops to prove that one branch of the logarithm is consistently selected.  With $g(z)=1/(1+f(z))$ the inverse does not give this problem and you can still prove $|g(z)|\le 1$.